# Consumir JSON con Angular. Error

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

Estoy tratando de consumir un json con angular y me está dando el error:

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | Prueba>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Type '{} | Prueba' is not assignable to type 'Prueba'.
>       Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Prueba'.
>         Property 'date' is missing in type '{}'.

Mi servicio:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  
  private urlTo = 'http://url.com/json/';

  getData(): Observable<Prueba> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlTo)
      .map((response: Response) => <Prueba>response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

La clase prueba:

```js
export class Prueba {
    public date: number;
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da el error, la del `.map(...)`?

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo @PabloLozano sobra el <Prueba> antes de response.json Ahora me autocontesto.

Comment: Era lo que sospechaba,tu código así creo que es equivalente a `(response as Prueba).json()` y el compilador se quejaba de eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi propio problema.

```js
 getData(): Observable<Prueba> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlTo)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Sobraba el `<Prueba>`

En la línea del map. Dónde ponía antes `<Prueba>.response.json()`